# How do I to connect on Google Drive using Java API on J2SE?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application created with J2SE and I want to connect on Google Drive to make download a file. Looking for some solution, I found the library `google-api-services-drive` which seems connect on it, I think, but I don't know how to use it with J2SE, I don't find any example using J2SE.

How could I to connect on Google Drive using this library ?

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags to questions!

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, Google provides the answer in the very first result of a search on "google drive java".
[Google drive Java API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3) has the maven dependencies you need, as well as an example project.

Looks like it's a few hundred lines of code, but most of it needed for the authentication so you can easily abstract it away into a utility class.

The core of connecting seems to come down to

```
      httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
  dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
  // authorization
  Credential credential = authorize();
  // set up the global Drive instance
  drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
      APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need google-api-java-client.
Look for this https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/drive-cmdline-sample